# How to approach this calculus question.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to look in different calculus questions in one textbook, and I found this one as interesting but pretty hard for me. I have only done high school calculus, so I don't know any tricks on how to approach this question or similar ones.

I tried integrating in couple different ways, however none of those worked. I'm not sure how to take derivative of an indefinite integral, since it seems not that straightforward.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^{0}\frac{t}{cost}dt$$

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: We mentioned it in our classes, however we didn't really work with it, so I'm not very experienced with it.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)\,dt=f(x)$. This is what you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that $\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt=-\int_b^af(t)\,\mathrm dt$. So$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_x^0\frac t{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt=-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^x\frac t{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt.$$And, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^x\frac t{\cos t}\,\mathrm dt=\frac x{\cos x}.$$

Comment: I thought this is not a valid step, because the variable in the integral is t not x.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that, if $f$ is continuous,$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^{0}\frac{t}{cost}dt = - \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{x}\frac{t}{cost}dt$$

Now use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Note that derivative of an anti-derivative is the original function.